# WordPress development?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

What's the most effective way to streamline WordPress theme development when moving from a dev to a production environment?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you a bit more specific about what exactly you mean? I have developed WordPress themes but honestly wouldn't know what to answer.

Comment: I've often found that building customized WP sites requires some use of category IDs or other unique elements to help flush out specific kinds of content. I'm looking for an easy way to version and streamline the deployment of a development "build" of a template into a production environment without nuking the database.

Answer (score 0):

First off don't use category ID numbers you should tie everything to category or tag slug since you can easily duplicate the slug when creating the new category.

```
        <?php // excludes testimonial category
        $slug = "testimonial";
        $category = get_category_by_slug($slug);
        query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-' .$category->cat_ID);
    ?>
```

Remove the - on cat to include a category by slug. After that I just FTP/SCP the theme up. You may want to look into getting a beanstalk account which does deployment for you with subversion and git deployment is coming.

http://beanstalkapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for mentioning beanstalk's deployment feature! I didn't know they had such a thing. When you're using SVN, do you store the whole WP instance or just the theme? What's your approach for managing the database differences between dev and production?

Comment: I just keep the wp-content folder excluding the uploads folder, which means I get the themes and all the plugins.

Regarding DB i don't make sure that they are exactly the same. I just make sure that I have some content that matches in each DB. So that they all have some posts. If there is a category that has some special function I just add a few items into it manually.